# Aries NamespaceHandler to get Reference of Bean

Tags: java, osgi, blueprint-osgi, aries

After successfully tried to implement my own blueprint interceptor to track method entry/exits using Namespace Handler, I'm now looking for enhancing it where the interceptor itself is defined as another bean in same blueprint xml and my namespace element use ref="interceptorBeanName". i.e., I'm trying to register an Interceptor that actually delegates to another Instance of Interceptor defined in the same blueprint.

But, how to get the Reference of Interceptor bean defined in the blueprint ?

I searched in Google for many hours. But, didn't any documentation of how to do that in Blueprint.

Any help on how to approach this will be highly appreciated.

**Edit:**

```
@Override
public ComponentMetadata decorate(Node node, ComponentMetadata compMeta,
        ParserContext cxt) {
    cxt.getComponentDefinitionRegistry().registerInterceptorWithComponent(compMeta, new Interceptor() {

        @Override
        public Object preCall(ComponentMetadata arg0, Method arg1, Object... arg2)
                throws Throwable {
            info_logger.info(arg1.getName() + " before call");
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void postCallWithReturn(ComponentMetadata arg0, Method arg1,
                Object arg2, Object arg3) throws Throwable {
            info_logger.info(arg1.getName() + " after call");
        }

        @Override
        public void postCallWithException(ComponentMetadata arg0, Method arg1,
                Throwable arg2, Object arg3) throws Throwable {
            info_logger.info(arg1.getName() + " after exception");
        }

        @Override
        public int getRank() {
            return 0;
        }
    });
    return compMeta;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two possibilities, use a BeanProcessor, or a ComponentDefinitionRegistryProcessor

The BeanProcessor is a classic bean, which can be injected like any other bean, but they can preprocess/postprocess other beans definition, and add an interceptor on this bean definition. this incerceptor can have reference on other beans

see for example the [tx annotation parser](https://github.com/apache/aries/blob/trunk/transaction/transaction-blueprint/src/main/java/org/apache/aries/transaction/parsing/AnnotationProcessor.java)

a ComponentDefinitionRegistryProcessor is invoked after the definition of the beans, but before the context is started. it can use the BlueprintContainer, which references all the beans of the context, and can add interceptor too. with the help of the BlueprintContainer, the interceptor can references other beans of the context.

see for example the [jpa processor](https://github.com/apache/aries/blob/trunk/jpa/jpa-blueprint/src/main/java/org/apache/aries/jpa/blueprint/impl/JpaComponentProcessor.java)

**Old Answer** :

If you want, in an aries-blueprint NamespaceHandler, create a reference to another bean, you can use the `RefMetaData`, and associate this ref like a normal bean.

```
private RefMetadata createRef(ParserContext context, String value) {
   MutableRefMetadata m = context.createMetadata(MutableRefMetadata.class);
   m.setComponentId(value);
   return m;
}
```

and something like :

```
MutableBeanMetadata metadata = context.createMetadata(MutableBeanMetadata.class);
metadata.addRuntimeClass(DelegateInterceptor.class);
...
metadata.addProperty("delegate", createRef(pc, element.getAttribute("ref")));
```

Comment: I understand that you're suggesting to use RefMetadata, but I couldn't get what this MutableBeanMetadata is used for and when/how is used? Can you please elaborate .

Comment: i thought you were implementing a new namespacehandler, i was wrong. i didn't understand your question.

Comment: Yes. I'm implementing new Namespace Handler. Just realized that DelegateInterceptor you've mentioned is my own Interface for which the bean has to be created & mentioned in ref attribute , correct ?

Comment: yep, you didn't post any code, so i just post an example to how inject a ref in another bean. this "delegateinterceptor" is your bean, which as a  reference to another interceptor - this reference is found in the blueprint container by name (ref)

Comment: Fine. But, how my `Interceptor` can actually call `delegate.preCall` - How to resolve the value for `delegate` is what I'm struck at. It would be great if you can show some sample or provide some pointers to the documentation.

Comment: post some code if you wants a more concrete example : the class, and the namespacehandler you're trying to implement

Comment: Have added the code where I have registered the interceptor. It's an anonymous class for now, which is just logging. I'll extract this as class which just delegates to say `delegate`; but then I need to know how I can pass the value for that `delegate` through the constructor. Only after I get the object by ref name, I can use that.

Comment: Thank you for the pointers. Will study about these & work out. Will come back to comment or Accept your answer :-)